# RevitPythonShell user input raw_input error

Tags: python, revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

Does anybody know how to fix this error in RevitPythonShell 2018.1.0.0?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz3QN.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, instead of posting a link to a picture, paste here the code and errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GTN, it looks like the code that is running the shell is trying to parse the line as code. That is probably due to how it tries to figure out what your input was. I remember being very confused with all of this when I first created RPS.

Instead, try doing this:

```
print("bunny rabbits lay eggs? yes/no")
answer = raw_input()
```

EDIT: I checked. It doesn't work.

Here's a solution that uses Forms:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")
from System.Drawing import Point
from System.Windows.Forms import Form, TextBox, Button, Label, TableLayoutPanel, DockStyle, DialogResult, AnchorStyles


class InputBox(Form):
    def __init__(self, question):
        self.Text = question

        self.tlp = TableLayoutPanel()
        self.tlp.RowCount = 3
        self.tlp.ColumnCount = 1
        self.tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        self.label = Label()
        self.label.Text = question
        self.label.AutoSize = True
        self.label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        self.label.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom
        self.tlp.Controls.Add(self.label)

        self.answer = TextBox()
        self.answer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        self.answer.AutoSize = True
        self.answer.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom
        self.tlp.Controls.Add(self.answer)

        self.ok = Button()
        self.ok.Text = "OK"
        self.ok.AutoSize = True
        self.ok.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom
        self.ok.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        self.tlp.Controls.Add(self.ok)

        self.Controls.Add(self.tlp)

def raw_input(question):
    input_box = InputBox(question)
    result = input_box.ShowDialog()
    if result == DialogResult.OK:
        return input_box.answer.Text

print raw_input("bunny rabbits lay eggs??")
```

Comment: Thanks Daren. I tried and it doesn't work either. Are there any other workarounds to prompt for and take user inputs in RPS?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working python 2.x or 3.x?

Check on the terminal: **python -V**

The below code is for python 2.x (for python 3 use input instead of raw_input):

```
answer = ''
while not answer:
    answer = raw_input("bunny rabbits lay eggs (y,n)? ").rstrip().lower()
```

Comment: Thanks Mahsa. I use python 2.x. It's what RPS is runny on. raw_input works fine in any other environment. just not on RPS for some reasons. Same applies for the code you shared.

Comment: @GTN Maybe it is because of this character '>' , please replace 'bunny rabbits lay eggs (y,n)?' with your sentence.